# Symfony 3.3 custom config file

Tags: symfony

I've very new to Symfony. Before I've used mostly Laravel.

Lets assume I have an API Key which I want to use here and there thru the project.
It doesn't feel right to store it as a class constant because I can't find any class to keep it in. And it seems pretty dumb to have it in various places thru the app as a string.

Normally using Laravel I would have used a config file specifically for this task.

However in symfony I can't seem to do the same(either that or my google-fu skills are pretty bad). If they are, a simple link to some documentation will do just fine.

So my question is: Where can I store various constants used thru the app?

Comment: Parameters.yml or environment variables. I'm sorry to say it, but I'm afraid your google-fu skills are pretty bad ;)

Comment: Ah, damn. And I remember reading about this. Thanks man. If you post it as an answer I'll accept it as soon as I can.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm sorry, but I'm afraid your Google-fu skills let you down this time.

Symfony.com has an excellent article about Configuration: [Configuration -
Symfony Best Practices](https://symfony.com/doc/current/best_practices/configuration.html)

The common way to save configuration parameters is by using `parameters.yml`. It supports environment variables as of Symfony 3.2.

The best practice for Symfony 2.x and 3.x:

> Define the infrastructure-related configuration options in the
>   app/config/parameters.yml file.

The best practice for Symfony 4:

> Define the infrastructure-related configuration options as environment
>   variables. During development, use the .env file at the root of your
>   project to set these.